# Connecting to Access database works when using VS but not ASP.Net localHost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I can connect to my Microsoft access database when I run my code in Visual Studio 2008, but not when I run it using ASP.net 2008. They both access the same database and use the same connect string:

`("Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\www_Pocket_Mirror_com\Webpage_Orig_Prod.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=False").`

The error that I am getting when running ASP.net is

> "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"

This has worked fine for years, but after the last auto updates by Windows 10 it no longer works. Can someone please help me debug this?

Comment: Is the ACE engine installed on your web server?  If you're connecting to an MDB file then you should probably use Jet rather than ACE.  Jet is basically part of Windows nowadays whereas ACE requires that either Office be installed or the database engine be installed standalone.

Comment: It may also be that the bittedness of your application is incompatible with the version of ACE that's installed.  Jet is 32-bit only whereas ACE comes in both 32-bit and 64-bit flavours.  It will almost always be the 32-bit version that's installed though, and that's what Microsoft recommends if you're installing Office.  That means that your app is generally going to have to be 32-bit as well, even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am using Microsoft.ace.oledb.12, but this is not SQL server. I am running this locally (LocalHost).  years ago when I first installed Visual Stidio 2008, and Microsoft Access 2010, I had to run AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255. After I did that everything worked perfecrly up to now.

Comment: I'm not sure why you bring up SQL Server.  I didn't say or even imply anything about SQL Server.  Anyway, if you have installed the 64-bit version of ACE then you need to make sure that your application is also 64-bit.  Perhaps the project properties were altered and it's being built as a 32-bit assembly now.

Answer (score 0):

Install the database engine. Try downloading it and install on your local machine.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255